# symfony 1.4 - inject current logged in user into Doctrine model

Tags: symfony1, dependency-injection, doctrine

I would like to inject, with full testability, the id of the current logged in user into a creator_id field of a Doctrine_Record class, without using the sfContext singleton. I found a couple of Doctrine behaviours like http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineActAsSignablePlugin, but they access the sfContext singleton in a listener or (in another example I found) in the save method of a subclass of Doctrine_Record.
I want to find a single entry point in the symfony controller, where I can inject the current logged in user and keep it till the end of the request.
How do I do?
Hope I have been clear enough.

EDIT:
As @jeremy suggested, I made a custom filter:

```
class userFilter extends sfFilter
{
  public function execute($filterChain)
  {
    $user = $this->getContext()->getUser();
    if ($user->isAuthenticated()) {
      $guard = $user->getGuardUser();
      Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setAttribute('logged_in_user', $guard->getId());
    }

    // Execute next filter
    $filterChain->execute();
  }
}
```

So now my tests and my tasks are sfContext free, I just have to set the proper user Id at some point before starting the interactions with the db:

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setAttribute('logged_in_user', sfConfig::get('default_user'));
```

Comment: I was thinking about adding the user id as a param of Doctrine_Manager instance when the user logs in, then get the param back anywhere in the model

Comment: Hi giorrrgio - could you elaborate a bit more? for example at the moment where do you need to use sfContext? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Great question! The use of `sfContext` everywhere is one of the uglier aspects of Symfony 1 and setting it on `Doctrine_Manager` sounds like a solid idea.

It's probably best to do this either in the `configureDoctrine` callback that happens in `ProjectConfiguration` (see below). I'm not 100% a user is present at this point, if it's not, your best bet is a custom filter ([reference](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_filters)).

```
public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager)
{
  $manager->setParam('user_id', sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising this question. I wrote the http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfAuditablePlugin with this in mind. I basically externalized the method that returns the userId so you can get the userId from session, doctrine parameter or wherever you have it.
Here are the settings to configure the method that returns an array containing user_id and user_name

```
  # Retrieve User Array from custom implementation
      # [0] => (int)user_id; [1] => (string)user_name;
  getUserArray:
    class_name: Utility
    static_method_name: getUserAuditArray
```

Comment: I will be publishing an update of this plugin in a weeks time, so let me know if there are bugs/issues. If it works, pl mark this answer & identify yourself as a plugin user on the symfony site :) thanks